# When are swift functions called in programs where no function call is visible?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mglmapview

[The example below](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/marker/) is taken from Mapbox, and shows how to mark a location on a map with an annotation. I understand that viewDidLoad is called when the app starts and thats what runs everything inside the viewDidLoad function.

I don't understand how the last two functions in this program are called(which both seem to have the name mapView). I see no reference to them inside viewDidLoad

```
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Set the map’s center coordinate and zoom level.
    mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7326808, longitude: -73.9843407), zoomLevel: 12, animated: false)
    view.addSubview(mapView)

    // Set the delegate property of our map view to `self` after instantiating it.
    mapView.delegate = self

    // Declare the marker `hello` and set its coordinates, title, and subtitle.
    let hello = MGLPointAnnotation()
    hello.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7326808, longitude: -73.9843407)
    hello.title = "Hello world!"
    hello.subtitle = "Welcome to my marker"

    // Add marker `hello` to the map.
    mapView.addAnnotation(hello)
  }

  // Use the default marker. See also: our view annotation or custom marker examples.
  func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    return nil
  }

  // Allow callout view to appear when an annotation is tapped.
  func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: They are delegate functions read about delegates here https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Comment: @MohmmadS I thought that might have been the case, but everything I look up has a different syntax for delegates, so is this some sort of shorthard?

Comment: read my explained answer @jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are delegate methods declared by protocol called `MGLMapViewDelegate` which is implemented to your class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate { ... }
```

By setting `delegate` of some object as your controller (`= self`) like you did with your `MGLMapView` in `viewDidLoad`

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

you're saying that when some method is called on `mapView`'s delegate, method which you've implemented like `mapView(_:viewFor:) -> MGLAnnotationView?` will be called.

---

Anyway, your `mapView` should be instance variable, otherwise you lost reference for it

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    var mapView: MGLMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: When is the method being called on the delegate though? I've looked at lots of tutorials and I haven't been able to find out how I find the spot where some sections of code says "execute the function mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {"  everything I find shows me how to create a delegate and how to create a protocol but since all of the code is local, it's obvious where it gets executed. 

And I didn't write the code myself, it's from that example I linked. I'm not concerned what needs to changed in it.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

with

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
```

is responsible for calling them , inside the **MapKit** frameWork the class `MKMapView` has a delegate property when you set the right delegate interally this happens

```
delegate?.mapView(self,//)
```

also you shouldn't return nil here

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
```

Comment: it's an optional `MGLAnnotationView?` he technically can return `nil`, but can you explain to me why he shouldn't i would like to know better

Comment: being optional does mean you can return nil , but this will hide the annotation as this method is called for every added annotation

Comment: oh thanks, so whenever i want to hide an annotation i would just return `nil`

Answer (score 0):

They are delegate functions, not ordinary function that you call, more like functions that get called based on an action, and you did set the `MapView.delegate` to `self` so when the functions gets called in the `MapView` regarding the case that called them they will get back to the implemented side in your `self` in this case the `UIViewController`, i suggest reading more about delegates [here](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef), so shortcut answer, the functions are not called in the same class.

Comment: How do I find out when the function gets called in the mapview, and if their not called in this class, how do I find the class that they're called in? Everything lesson or tutorial I look at builds the code from scratch so It's obvious in the lesson.